# Convergence of Series (Comparison Test)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Convergence of Series $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$

I think The solution is to compare the original $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}}$ with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n^2}}$
but I don't understand why this step is taken

Comment: `I don't understand why` Terms larger than those of a series that diverges to $+\infty$ means $\cdots$

Comment: I misquoted the problem

Comment: instead of minus, it is a plus. sorry for misquoting the problem. question remains unanswered

Comment: Just use dxiv's hint.

Comment: Still the same. That series must be divergent

Comment: The expression 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n^2}}$$
simplifies to ??

Comment: @dxiv good to know, but I am asking why the answer for similar problems use this similar type comparison

Comment: @quasi it simplifies to 1/(sqrt(2)(n))

??

Comment: @mathguy Because you try to find a simpler series to compare to, which you know how it behaves. In this case, that series is the harmonic series $\sum 1/n\,$, which you know that diverges.

Comment: The idea is to make the terms smaller, so that after the change, the new series is more obviously divergent.

Comment: i think i understand, it just seemed like an unusual way to reach a solution. thank you

Comment: The series whose $n$-th term is
$$\frac{1}{n\sqrt{2}}$$
is just a positive constant times the harmonic series, hence is divergent, right? But which is bigger, your original series, or the new one?

Comment: The problem term in simplifying the original square root is the +1. Change it to $n^2$ and the problem goes away (and the comparison works in your favor).

Comment: interesting trick, but it wasnt intuitive to me. thanks for explaining

Comment: No problem -- put that one in your "trick bag". Tricks are reusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$ n^2 + 1 \leq n^2 + n^2 = 2n^2 $$
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}n} $$
Since these two terms are always nonnegative, we see that, by the Direct Comparison Test:
$$ \sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} \quad \text{converges} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}n} \quad \text{converges} $$

The right sum diverges since it is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sum \frac{1}{n}$, a scalar multiple of the Harmonic series, which diverges. Therefore, the original sum diverges.

---

If you do not want to use the Direct Comparison Test, you can also use the Limit Comparison Test:

We note that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1/n^2}{1/(n^2+1)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2+1}{n^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[1 + \frac{1}{n^2} \right] = 1 $$
Since the square root function is continuous, this implies that:
\begin{align*}
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{1/n^2}{1/(n^2+1)}} &= \sqrt{1} \\
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1/n}{1/\sqrt{n^2+1}} &= 1
\end{align*}

Therefore, by the Limit Comparison Test:
$$ \sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} \quad\text{converges} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \sum \frac{1}{n} \quad\text{converges}$$
The right sum is the Harmonic series, which diverges. Therefore, the original sum diverges.